# getting 'not defined' output from function

Tags: python, database, function

Hi codinglovers could you help me with below code, I dont understand where I am making mistake. I am getting error: name is not defined.

```py
def split_data(my_data, split_ratio=[3,1,1]):

    traning_data=my_data[0:int(split_ratio[0]/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]),:]
    testing_data=my_data[int((split_ratio[0]+split_ratio[1])/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]) :, :]
    validation_data=my_data[int(split_ratio[0]/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]):int((split_ratio[0]+split_ratio[1])/sum(split_ratio)*data.shape[0]),:]
    
    return training_data, validation_data, testing_data
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-c35872623a17> in <module>()
----> 1 training_data, validation_data, testing_data = split_data(data, [3,1,1])
      2 print(traning_data.shape)
      3 print(validation_data.shape)
      4 print(testing_data.shape)

<ipython-input-60-aedad770c096> in split_data(my_data, split_ratio)
      5 
      6 
----> 7   return training_data, validation_data, testing_data
      8 

NameError: name 'training_data' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo in the code: `traning_data` should be `training_data`